# Mount Everest climb cost and total time

Tags: nepal, mount-everest

I am from Bangladesh. How can I climb Mount Everest, for a reasonable price?

How much does it cost to climb Mount Everest? And how much time does this campaign usually take?

Comment: The climbing license alone is enough to break you without some serious sponsorship.

Comment: If you are asking this question on a generic travel forum like this, one has to wonder if you have enough climbing experience for such an expedition.

Comment: This would be more on topic for outdoors.SE.

Comment: [Looking for a way to get your name on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_who_died_climbing_Mount_Everest)?

Comment: What do you mean by reasonable price? That's a very personal issue. It costs 1,000x the Bangladeshi minimum wage. That is $50,000.

Comment: There's probably a waiting list to climb, so it gives you a couple of years to get in shape and get the money.

Comment: @Tom, the good news is that the usual route up Everest isn't a particularly technical climb.  You don't need to learn rock-climbing, just how to handle yourself on snow, ice, and absurdly thin air.

Comment: @Mark - that attitude is why rich tourists (and sometimes their guides) die trying to reach a summit.  Ice, snow and high altitude skills require lots of experience to learn same as rock climbing.  No way am I roping up with an inexperienced person on an ascent of that nature.

Comment: @QuoraFeans The minimum wage in Bangladesh is $50?  In the US, people are struggling to achieve a minimum wage of $15.

Comment: @phoog: I mean the minimum wage per month.

Comment: [David Sharp](https://archive.seattletimes.com/archive/?date=20060715&slug=webeverest16) *had signed on with Asian Trekking's International Everest Expedition I, a loose grouping of individuals and smaller teams, paying about $6,200 for a bare-bones package*

Comment: *The median price Nepali operators charged in the 2019 spring season was around $40,000* https://www.outsideonline.com/2400987/mount-everest-crowds-new-rules-nepal

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I have not climbed mount Everest, but I just came back from Pokhara, Nepal after some treks. I also went to the Himalayan Mountain Institute in Darjeeling, which is possibly the nearest place for you to get some experience before going on your adventure.

**On a generous ballpark figure, I would say it will cost you about $50,000 (USD) for the entire trip.**

The cost will depend on these

- The permit.
- Insurance (mandatory)
- Porters, guides, transport.
- Food.
- Trekking gear.

[This web page](http://www.alanarnette.com/blog/2015/12/21/everest-2016-how-much-does-cost-to-climb-mount-everest/) (not affiliated) has a detailed breakdown of the costs.

It takes a lot of previous trekking experience to climb mount Everest. Basically any peak higher than 8,000m will be expensive. Usually people find someone to sponsor them, because doing the trek by yourself is beyond many of our financial limits. If you are a scout, an athlete, etc, you can probably find someone to sponsor for you.

Second best thing to climbing mt. Everest is climbing up to a base camp. They are often very cheap, and you will not need to buy expensive gear either. If you are in Kathmandu or Pokhara, the trekking companies will *find you* with their offers. You can arrange them yourself easily too.

A trek to Anapurna base camp will only cost about $250 with the permit and insurance, and gear hired. Note that food can be expensive, so we brought most of our food in our bags (breads, dry food, etc). It will take about 10-14 days for the entire trip.

For even cheaper treks, Poonhill would be your best bet. It takes about 4 days, and is less expensive than all other options.

In my opinion, Anarpurna is a great experience for a fraction of cost to climb mt. Everest.

Comment: You definitely don't need a guide to go to the Annapurna base camp :) Just get a map and follow the path. Ask people around. Will be a much cheaper and (as far as I'm concerned) better experience. I had to pay 42$ per person for the permit (TIMS and Annapurna conservation entry fee), and the food and accommodation cost me between 10 and 25$ per day, depending on how far you are into the trek.

Answer (score 12):

It costs a hefty amount of $30000 to $80000 but on average most people pay around $45000.It also depends on whether you take a Tibetian route or the route from Nepal. But the expense largely depends on the cost of the following components:

**travel up to base camp $5000-$10000**

**permit & insurance $7000-$11000**

**climbing fee $10000-$15000**

**insurance, supplies &misc $10000-$20000**

This is just estimated cost ,and the actual cost may vary for further info you can visit the official site of the Nepal Mountaineering Association:
**[nepalmountaineering.org](https://nepalmountaineering.org)**.

Well talking about time, it usually takes about one month but without considering the time for preparation and training.

Comment: Here is the official website from Nepal,this has all the related info on climbing Mount Everest or any other peak. nepalmountaineering.org

Comment: From the page you linked: "The short answer is, site a car, cialis or at least $30, discount 000 but most people pay about $45,000. "  Not only does that sentence contain nonsense, but it also contains spammy links.

Comment: Hey, later I discovered the official website. It's nepalmountaineering.org please visit it and get all the authentic information.

Comment: Well my friend like you can't judge a book by it's cover you can't judge that info just by seeing first two sentence go through the post and cross check the info...

Comment: @BudhathokiBijaya That site has clearly been taken over by spammers. Don't send them more traffic.

Comment: Friends I removed the previous link and put the official link in place. Thanks everybody for the suggestion.

Comment: Are these figures meant to be USD? It's not clear and it seems like they are very different from the figure quoted in the other answer.